# Get a custom tag (containing colon) value using jquery

Tags: jquery, custom-tag

I have one custom tag. I want to set value to that custom tag using jquery.
Though it look a silly question i spent more time in searching result for that.

My tag is

```
<error:description code="12345" type="error" result="description" />${description}
```

Now i want the get that tag and have to pass the values using jquery.

Please help me how to do this.

I have no `things i tried area` because i not even know how to start.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the colon using two back-slashes, so just do

```
$('error\\:description').attr("result"); //to get result attribute
$('error\\:description').text(); //to get the related text
```

Comment: its giving undefined for $('error\\:description').attr("result");

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it:

```
jQuery("error\\:description").text("your text");
```

Comment: I tryed it and it works quite fine for me. `jQuery("error\\:description")` finds the `<error:description code="12345" type="error" result="description" />` element.